# Hadoop distcp to copy hive tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to hadoop and hive, I am trying to use
hadoop distcp -overwrite hdfs://source_cluster/apps/hive/warehouse/test.db hdfs://destination_cluster/apps/hive/warehouse/test.db

this command runs properly and there is no error, still I can't see test.db on the target hdfs cluster

Comment: post your full command

Answer (score 0):

You've copied files, but haven't modified the Hive metastore that actually registers table information.

If you want to copy between clusters, I suggest looking into a tool called [Circus Train](https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/circus-train), otherwise, use SparkSQL to interact with the Hiveserver of both cluster rather than use hdfs only tooling

Answer (score 0):

After copying files and directories, it is necessary to recreate the tables (ddl) so that data about those tables appears in the metastore